# Understanding concurrent.futures.Executor.map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to parallelize some Python code using processes and [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). It looks like I can execute a function multiple times in parrallel either by [submitting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) calls and then calling [`Future.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) on the futures, or by using [`Executor.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map).
I'm wondering if the latter is just a syntactic sugar for the former and if there's any difference performance-wise. It doesn't seem immediately clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

It will allow you to execute a function multiple times concurrently instead true parallel execution.

Performance wise, I recently found that the `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()` and `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` consumed the same amount of compute time to complete the same task. Note: `.submit()` returns a future object (let's call it f) and you need to use it's `f.result` option to see it's result. On the other hand, `.map()` directly returns an iterator.

When converting their results into an ordered list using the sorted method, I have found that compute time of the entire `.map()`code can be faster than entire `.submit()` code in certain scenarios.

When converting their results into an unordered list using the list method, the compute time of the entire `.submit()` and `.map()` codes are the same. Also, these codes performed faster than the codes using the sorted method.

You can read the details in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42096963/5722359). There, I have also shared my codes where you can see how they work. I hope they can be helpful to you.

I have not used `ThreadPoolExecutor` so I can't comment in detail. However, I have read that they are implemented the same way as the `ProcessPoolExecutor` and they are more suited to be used for I/O bound tasks instead of CPU bound tasks. You do need to specify the *`max_workers`* argument, i.e. the max number of threads, whereas in the `ProcessPoolExecutor` `max_workers` is an optional argument which defaults to the number of CPUs returned by `os.cpu_count()`.